# Disabling the "Length Authoring Tools" (css unit selector) in Chrome Devtools Inspector

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

**The undesired functionality**

In Chrome 95 there was introduced new functionality where the user can hover and click on the unit part of a css value to hotswap the unit.

The feature is part of a package solution that has been labeled "**Length Authoring Tools**" in the release notes, and can be seen in action and described in detail in the [release notes on the official blog](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-95/#length).


How can this feature be disabled?

**Issue 1:**

[image]

If a css-line in the inspector says `padding: 0 10px;` then the user can click the `px`-part of the line and open a selector that let's the user swap `px` to other units such as `rem`,`vmax` or `in`.

Clicking this part of the value no longer lets the user edit the entire value quickly. Most users already know what unit they desire to use beforehand, so they do not need to be helped to accidentally select `pt` or `vw` when working exclusively with `px` everywhere else.

**Issue 2:**

[image: Ctrl+C][image: After Ctrl+V]

When selecting and copying properties from the inspector there is now inserted whitespaces/new lines between the value and the unit since the unit portion seems to be considered a separate element. This makes prototyping in the devtools and copy/pasting to external documents very tedious and broken.

Comment: It can't be disabled. I think it was a mistake to push this feature so aggressively without an option to disable it. I reported both issues: https://crbug.com/1259073, https://crbug.com/1259088.

Comment: They've made a fix (in the source code) for both issues just now, https://imgur.com/a/ytETSxL, so hopefully it'll be back-merged into Chrome 95 soon. Chrome Canary will have the fix in a day or two. The [snapshot builds](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/) should have it today, probably.

Comment: I'm a bit frustrated that they pushed this feature without a toggle option. That there is a rapid fix in progres is very good news though.

Comment: I am also struggling with this. Forced to work in firefox for a day or two because it does not have those "functions". Sadly, edge has it as well since it is chromium based. Anyway if they fix it soon I do not bother but yes they pushed it too aggressively.

Comment: They have fixed it and the fix will be released in 3 weeks according to there [twitter](https://twitter.com/ChromeDevTools/status/1453711393895555072)

Comment: We should send them an invoice for all the time wasted being angry about that foolish feature. FYI Chrome 96 it is much more tolerable, and you can still disable it. Just remember dev tools has its own settings menu. right click anything, inspect element,  then click the gear icon in the popup.

Comment: Finally, I found someone who finds this really annoying ... I style a page 99.85% of the time using the Inspect element and this feature is just so annoying when you copy the CSS over to your IDE (the unit gets all messed up). I tried downloading Opera browser but they use chromium as well

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Updated answer 2021-11-16:

##### An option has been added to disable Length Authoring Tools in Chrome 96.

The following is mentioned in the [official release notes](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-96/#length) for Chrome 96.

To disable Length Authoring Tools, navigate to this location in the DevTools and uncheck the checkbox:
**Settings** > **Experiments** > **Enable CSS length authoring tools in the Styles pane**.

[image: How to disable Length Authoring Tools]

#### But...

###### The main issues regarding Length Authoring Tools have also been fully remedied in Chrome 96.

The initial incentive to disable these tools has been greatly diminished because of this.

A chevron will now appear to the right of the hovered value instead of reacting to clicks to the entire unit portion of it.

[image: Length Authoring Tool displaying chevron to the right]

Copy paste now also works as intended.

[image: Selected css prepared for Copy]
[image: Copy/Paste result]

**Conclusion**:
It is now possible to disable the Length Authoring Tools, but you might no longer need to.

---

**Old answer:**

##### ***You can't.***

###### (Though fixes are coming!)

It is not possible to toggle this feature in the current live stable release ( ***Chrome 95.0.4638.69*** ).

Fixes have been added to Chromium ( [[1]](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1259073), [[2]](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1259088), [[3]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Bmi.jpg) ) that are slowly making their way to the stable release of Chrome.

**But help is on its way...**

**Chrome 96** is scheduled to be released on **November 16 2021** ([source](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule)), or ~3 weeks after October 28 according to [this official tweet](https://twitter.com/ChromeDevTools/status/1453711393895555072). It will at least contain a revert to free text editing of css properties ([source](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1259088#c22)). Hopefully version 96 will address the issue completely, but if it doesn't then the next major release is scheduled for **January 4 2022** (If this issue is unresolved by then somebody at Google should be fired).

As for now, [Chrome Canary](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) seems to have these fixes implemented and might be considered an alternative solution to the issue if you find the current state of Length Authoring Tools unbearable.

**Please be advised that Chrome Canary can be quite unstable.**

**This question and answer will be edited and corrected once there are real fixes in the live stable version.**

Comment: Chrome 96 was released and this feature is reverted

Comment: Chrome 96 lets you edit the values again, and the copy-pasting is fixed too. The unit selector was moved to a little dropdown menu next to the CSS value.