# In Chrome, how can you disable the new size dropdown when you click on a size (e.g. font-size: 20px)

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

A recent update of Chrome must have added the feature of selecting units via a dropdown in Inspector when you click on the value.

This behaviour, for me, causes issues and I would like to disable it. The issues it produces for me are:

1. Clicking on the value to adjust the amount (e.g. change 20px to 18px) shows the dropdown selector to change units. I do not use mouse wheel scrolling to change it as its not accurate enough, too sensitive.
2. To be able to change the value, I have to click on the left edge of the number and it seems tricky to select and takes me longer to code
3. When I now copy and paste the CSS from Inspector into my code, it adds line breaks after the value and semi-colon, I assume due to the dropdown being there. I have to then manually remove the line breaks.

This is how copy and paste ends up:

```
.question-summary h3, .question-summary .result-link {
    margin-bottom: 4
px
;
    font-size: 1.15384615rem;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69719071/disabling-the-length-authoring-tools-css-unit-selector-in-chrome-devtools-in

Comment: Haha exact same issues! Thanks. Looks like we have to wait then.

Comment: They provided a way to disable it, thank goodness. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69719071/disabling-the-length-authoring-tools-css-unit-selector-in-chrome-devtools-in/69822231#69822231